# Inconsistent behavior AWS API gateway . Getting a 403 for an API that was working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a few API that have been working for a while. All of them are secured with an API key. For some reason all of them have stopped working and are throwing a 403,Error from cloudfront. None of them have any caching mechanism enabled. When I test my Lambda function via AWS console for these API endpoints, things work. In an attempt to recreate the issue, I pointed one of my test api endpoints to the lambda function without API keys. And that worked. Then I added API keys to the API and re-deployed it. Funnily enough, I was able to Postman them without passing x-api-key header. For this test API end point the response for Cache is X-Cache →Miss from cloudfront.

There is No difference in the setup for the my original API/test API. This behavior is inconsistent and without it my app function at all.

Comment: Are you sure that you have not changed CloudFront configurations towards authentication? `error 403` means Unauthorized access

Comment: Yes.I am not using cloud front . None of the Apis have caching enabled

Comment: But you told that you are using it **throwing a 403,Error from cloudfront**

Comment: That's the weird bit. I don't understand why.

Comment: What region are you in and when did this start happening? Can you post on the AWS forums so we can investigate?

Comment: Also, you say it's inconsistent. Does that mean it's *not* happening for 100% of your calls now?

Comment: The behaviour is inconsistent for following reasons:

Answer (score 5):

There was an update that was rolled out that affected a small number of customers using API Keys. Unfortunately it seems like you were one of the customers affected. We believe we have corrected the issue and you should no longer see 403s from your API when using a valid API Key.

**Note:** The reason you see CloudFront headers is that API Gateway creates a CloudFront distribution for each api.

Comment: Thanks Bob . Everything is running as expected now. Would be good to some how get notified in such scenarios, since there isn't much to do other than wonder if it was due some change made by the end devs like me.

Answer (score -1):

Just regenerate your key and it should work as expected.